# ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated in update query

Tags: oracle12c

```
delete table(select c.investment from clientt c where c.cname='Jhon smith')i
where i.company=(select ref(s) from stockk s where s.company='INFOSYS');

insert into table(select c.investment from clientt c where c.cname='Jill Brody')i
values (investment_ty ((select ref(s) from stockk s where s.company='GM'),64.00,'11-AUG-2001',1000));
```

Question:-

Suppose Jhon sold his INFOSYS stocks to Jill, and Jill sold her GM stoks to Jhon today at the current prices. Update the database for these two transaction.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please let us where is the update query as mentioned in the title?

Comment: I think row delete and entering new values to row. It's a update query .